# Cannot read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml after minor changes

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I made some minor changes in my app but now when i try to build my app im getting this error that says Cannot read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml ill post both manifest and gradle properties here so you can get better understanding of what happens :
Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.soheil.prolightfa"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="24"
    android:versionName="4.6.1">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="28" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- pushe -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.soheil.prolightfa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.soheil.prolightfa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <!-- pushe -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/lablelasli"
        android:label="@string/labelasli"
        android:logo="@drawable/lablelasli"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/labelasli"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- service flashlight -->
        <service
            android:name=".utils.FlashlightService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".screenlight"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".policesiren"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ambulance"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".firetruck"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".constrc"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".camflash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".disco"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".more"
            android:label="@string/labelasli"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <receiver android:name=".widget">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- pushe -->
        <receiver android:name="co.ronash.pushe.receiver.UpdateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

                <data
                    android:path="com.soheil.prolightfa"
                    android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.soheil.prolightfa" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="co.ronash.pushe.token"
            android:value="PUSHE_4xxxxxx" />
        <!-- pushe -->

        <activity android:name=".morseract" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Color"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <receiver android:name=".utils.DisplayNotifications" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="xxxxxxx"/>

    </application>
```

and here is my gradle looks like

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/woxingxiao/maven' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }

    }
    dependencies {
        // Add dependency
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    //crashlytics
    // Check for v11.4.2 or higher
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    //
    //    // Add dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    //pushe
    implementation project(':pushe-lib-1.2.0')
    //adad
    implementation 'ir.adad:androidsdk:5.0.0'
    //seekbar
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.github.rtugeek:colorseekbar:1.7.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.xw.repo:bubbleseekbar:3.5-lite'
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.3.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            }
        }

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Everything else is correct i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see your applicationId in the `android { }` definition.

```
// ...
android {
    // ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.soheil.prolightfa"
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Comment: get through documentation and correct your gradle file https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#module-level then you can delete the unneeded references from `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thank you i fixed my gradle and removed the last line of gradle !apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'